# Why is this test result backwards?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, shoulda

I'm writing my first tests using Test:Unit and Shoulda, so this may be a simple misunderstanding on my part, but given a Pages model that contains no validation, and a test:

```
#test/unit/page_test.rb    
require 'test_helper'

class PageTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  should belong_to(:site)
  should validate_presence_of(:slug)
end
```

The second test fails as expected (given there's no validation in the Model):

```
# Running tests:

[2/2] PageTest#test: Page should require slug to be set.  = 0.02 s
  1) Failure:
test: Page should require slug to be set. (PageTest) [/Users/Matt/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/shoulda-context-1.1.1/lib/shoulda/context/context.rb:339]:
Did not expect errors to include "can't be blank" when slug is set to nil, got error: 

Finished tests in 0.115436s, 17.3256 tests/s, 17.3256 assertions/s.
2 tests, 2 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

However the error message `Did not expect errors to include "can't be blank" when slug is set to nil` seems backwards. Shouldn't that read: `Expected errors to include "can't be blank"`, because if the validation I'm testing for existed, you'd expect an error from the validation that slug "can't be blank" when slug is nil.

The test passes if I add the validation, but I'd like to see it fail correctly first!

Also, why does the first test pass? My Pages model doesn't contain a `belongs_to` association!

Testing sucks! :-(

Comment: On which object is 'should' being called upon? Shouldn't your test have a context and description? And where is the'it' clause? This is RSpec, isn't it?

Comment: No, Test::Unit with shoulda - thought it best to learn "the Rails way" before getting fancy with RSpec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in older versions of `shoulda`. You can see [this thread](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/pull/295) for more info.

When I updated to the latest version (2.2.0 right now), I see the correct behavior and message like `Expected errors to include...`.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. It's a shame my first test found this bug in shoulda, as it put me off this combo, and I moved on to RSpec instead (the luxury of being a test newbie an not comitted to one suite). I was amused (and a little surprised) though to read in the linked thread that shoulda has poor test coverage in places! ;-)

Comment: RSpec is a testing suite, and "shoulda" is one of its many "languages", if you will. I hear you that you might have been put off but I've used them long enough to still heartily recommend 'em both.